# Error **This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created** while deploying contract

Tags: contract-development

I had to create contract. 
    The description of task is:
    Voting Contract
    Create a contract, that:
    •   Is Owned
    •   Can be killed
    •   Uses safe math operations
    •   Has members (people that are member of the contract)
    •   The owner is the first member
    •   The owner can remove members
    •   To add a new member, there needs to be a voting
    o   If >50% of the members agree, the new member is added
    •   For each member we hold:
    o   His address
    o   ETH donated to the contract
    o   Timestamp of last donation
    o   Value of last ETH donation
    •   A member can be removed from the contract if he hasn’t donated to the contract in the last 1 hour
    •   Use a library for all member related actions

The code is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract Owned {
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner!!");
        _;
    }

    constructor (address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }

}

contract VotingContract is Owned {

    /* --- Structures and variables --- */
    struct Member {
        address member;
        uint donatedETH; // ETH donated to the contract
        uint since; // Timestamp of last donation
        uint lastDonatedETH; // Value of last ETH donation
    }

    mapping (address => uint) public memberId;
    Member[] public members;

    address public owner;

    SafeMathHelper public math;

    // This is a type for a single proposal.
    struct Proposal
    {
        address memberAddress; // address
        //bool voted; // true -> yes, false -> no
    }
    //Proposal[] public proposals;

    /* --- Events --- */
    event MembershipAccepted(string desc, address member, bool isMember);
    event MembershipRemoved(string desc, address member);

    /* --- Modifiers --- */
    modifier onlyMembers {
        require(memberId[msg.sender] != 0);
        _;
    }



    constructor (address _owner) public payable{
        owner = _owner;
        uint id = 0;
        memberId[owner] = 0; // 
        members[id] = Member({member: _owner, donatedETH: msg.value, since: now, lastDonatedETH: msg.value});

    }

    /* --- Functions --- */
    function addMember (address _memberAddress)  
                onlyMembers 
                payable
                public 
                returns(bool) 
                {

        uint id = memberId[_memberAddress];
        if (id == 0) {
            memberId[_memberAddress] = members.length;
            id = members.length++;
        }

        bool votingOfMembers = Voting();
        if (votingOfMembers) {
            members[id] = Member({member: _memberAddress, donatedETH: msg.value, since: now, lastDonatedETH: msg.value});
            emit MembershipAccepted("Member is added", _memberAddress, true);
            return true;            
        } 
        else return false;

    }


    //  To add a new member, there needs to be a voting
    function Voting () public 
            onlyMembers 
            returns(bool) {
        // the member has put true/false to vote for the targetMember
        Proposal[] proposals;
        uint yesVotes = 0;
        uint noVotes = 0;
        uint numOfAllVotes = members.length;
        bool voteYes; // clicked on button YES -> true
        bool voteNo; // clicked on button NO -> true
        bool votedForMember = false;

        while(math.add(yesVotes, noVotes) <= numOfAllVotes){
        //while(yesVotes + noVotes <= numOfAllVotes){
            for (uint i = 0; i < numOfAllVotes; i++) {

                for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++)
                    {
                    if (proposals[p].memberAddress == msg.sender)
                        {
                            votedForMember = true;
                        }
                    } // votedForMember stays false if member is not voted

                if (!votedForMember ) {
                    // add voted address to proposal:    
                    proposals.push(Proposal({
                        memberAddress : msg.sender
                        //, voted: true
                        }));

                    if (voteYes == true) {
                        yesVotes++;
                    } else if (voteNo == true) {
                        noVotes++;
                    }            
                }
            }
        }

        // If >50% of the members agree, the new member is added
        if (math.div100(yesVotes, numOfAllVotes) < 0.5*100) {
            // no voted
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }


    //The owner can remove members
    function removeMember(address _memberAddress) 
            public
            onlyOwner
        {
            uint id =  memberId[_memberAddress]; // 

            if (id != 0) {
                //remove id from array
                //members[id] = Member({member: _owner, donatedETH: msg.value, since: now});  
                delete  memberId[_memberAddress];
                removeFromMembers(id);
                emit MembershipRemoved("Removed member: ", _memberAddress); 
            }
        }

    function removeFromMembers(uint index) public onlyOwner {
    // returns uint[]
    // if (index >= array.length) return;
        if (index < members.length) {
            for (uint i = index; i<members.length-1; i++){
                members[i] = members[i+1];
            }
            delete members[members.length-1];
            members.length--;
            //return array;
        }

    }

function killContract () public 
                onlyOwner 
                {
        selfdestruct(owner); //Can be killed
    }


}


contract SafeMathHelper {
    // Uses safe math operations
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a && c >= b);
        return c;
    }

    function mult(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b || b == 0 || c / b == a);
        return c;
    }

    function div100(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint c = (a / b) * 100;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

When I try to deploy VotingContract I'm getting an issue: 
    **This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created.**
I commented all functions of VotingContract one by one (or two of them) to check whether it will be deployed but with no success. No matter which function/functions are commented I was getting the same error.
Any ideas are highly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're never calling the parent constructor. Try this:

```
constructor(address _owner) Owned(_owner) public payable {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I succeeded to deployed but I've got error: VM error:invalid opcode.

Comment: Well yes, your constructor is immediately writing past the end of a zero-length array. This is one of _many_ bugs you'll find in this code. :-)

Comment: Would you be so kind to point at the bugs as I'm learning now Solidity? Thank you.